# How to build a select menu using STI types in rails with simple_form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, single-table-inheritance, sti

I'm new to STI and I'm trying to build a select menu that lists all the STI types in a Model. I am using simple_form and Rails 4.1.  How do I get a drop down menu with the StiRecord.types? I'd like to store the type in the database in a string.

```
def new
  @record = Record.new
  @sti_records = StiRecord.subclasses.collect{|x| x.to_s}
end
```

example subclass

```
class SampleStiRecord < StiRecord
end
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.input :restricted_to, wrapper_html: {class: 'col-md-3 col-md-offset-2'}, collection: @sti_records %>
```

Comment: What part of your solution doesn't work the way you'd like it to?

Comment: Nothing shoes up in the select menu.  I would like to get a list of all the available subclasses.   Is this possible or would I have to write a helper form?

Comment: If you evaluate `StiRecord.subclasses.collect{|x| x.to_s}` in your `rails console`, does it return a list of subclasses? Or an empty array? This might be an issue with the classes not being loaded, due to Rails' autoloader.

Comment: It comes up empty in the console.

Comment: Per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18239012/rails-sti-subclasses-dont-show-up-unless-used, my hypothesis about the subclasses not showing up unless used looks to be correct. There are things you could to do to eagerly load all of the classes (in fact, Rails is configured to do this in prod anyway), but your best bet might be to skip the metaprogramming and just hard-code (or store somewhere in the database) your list of record types.

Answer (score 2):

In your parent model you can define a method to get them:

`def self.types
    unscoped.select(:type).distinct.pluck(:type)
  end`

Then just use `Model.types` and you'll get an array with the types present in the database.

If you want to see all the defined types, you'll need to go to the classes way, to check which classes are defined.

You can do it with:

`Model.descendants.map {|klass| klass.name.demodulize }`

Although remember that you have to set the `config.eager_load = true` in the development environment, otherwise it will not work, unless you have already loaded all the classes.

Also remember, sometimes the best way it's the dumbest way, so you could just create an array with the types. Everytime you will create a new type, you'll need to create a model... so it's was just a matter of adding another element to the array.

Answer (score 1):

[Paulo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52475983/299774) is not bad, but it has a major problem: it will list types that are already saved in the DB, not those that have defined subclasses. This might work for you, but not necessarily.

The biggest problem is that, after you've introduced a new type your prod ENV would not show such type to be chosen from, because no such record has been added yet. You'd need to add a "dummy" record to allow users to pick such type or do other weird hacks.

Eager load works as well, but it's such a big change to the whole dev process for this minor issue (in big apps you can work for ages to load rails console with preloading, stuff that can make devs quit for other employers)

He mentions the dumbest way with an array and I want to expand on that:

Define possible values for the `type` attribute using enum declaration:

```rb
class StiRecord
  enum type: %w[OneType OtherType].to_h { |v| [v,v] }
  # ...
```

And now you can do

```
StiRecord.types
=> {"OneType" => "OneType", "OtherType" => "OtherType"}
```

And your solution does not depend on records existing in the database.

It's not ideal, you need to repeat yourself: When adding a new subclass, you also have to mention it in the enum declaration.